# Rails: url_to scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In the following piece of code (of course in a view) I have `<td><%= post.full_hsh %></td>` displaying correctly the value of the field `post.full_hsh`, but `url_for` gives an error: `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit", :id=>nil}`.

Why is `post.full_hsh` correct in a row and `nil` in the row below? Thanks

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= truncate post.body, :length => 100, :separator => ' ' %>...</td>
   <td><%= post.created_at %></td>
   <td><%= post.full_hsh %></td>      
   <td><%= url_for :controller => 'posts', :action => 'edit', :id => post.full_hsh %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**:

my `routes.rb` file:

```
get "admin/index"

root :to => 'home#index'

#access posts via /posts/ab123c or /p/ab123c
resources :posts, :path => 'p', :except => [:new, :index, :delete]
resources :posts, :except => [:new, :index, :delete]

match '/p/:id/delete' => 'posts#delete', :as => 'posts_delete'
match '/admin' => 'admin#index'
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Can you also give us an idea of what `post.full_hsh` might look like?

Comment: it's a plain sha1 hash: '9e60d55edf826483672497b22f9da794571b1275'

Comment: oh, i found the problem some of the earliests "posts" didn't have it set, so printing them just yields a blank line, but in url_for it rises an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post.full_hsh` is an attribute of the `post` objection.  you probably want `:id => post` instead

You want to generate the URL based on the object itself, in this case `post`, not on the attribute of an object (`post.full_hsh`)

Comment: hi. no, i'm sorry, i need to generate a custom link based on the full_hsh attribute of the Post model.